# Problems adding roles to a user model in Laravel 4

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm having some trouble using Eloquent models and not sure if I am missing something. I have a User model and a Role model with a many to many relationship set up in Laravel 4...

```
// Find a user with their roles (none at the moment)
$user = User::with('roles')->find(2);
var_dump($user->toJson());
```

Notice the empty roles array, which is expected

```
{
  "id":"2","username":"Test","email":"test@example.com","remember_token":"",
  "roles":[]
}
```

Next, I attach a role to the user and show the user again...

```
$user->roles()->attach($role);
var_dump($user->toJson());
```

**Now we have attached a role to the user, but the roles array is still empty**

```
{
    "id":"2","username":"Test","email":"test@example.com","remember_token":"",
    "roles":[]
}
```

If I try and fetch the user again, the roles show up fine, so the DB is being updated correctly...

```
$user = User::with('roles')->find(2);
var_dump($user->toJson());

{
    "id":"2","username":"Test","email":"test@example.com","remember_token":"",
    "roles":[{"id":"1","name":"Admin","pivot":{"user_id":"2","role_id":"1"}}]
}
```

My Question: How come after I attach a role to my user model, it does not show up in the model until I reload it from the DB. I would have expected it to be reflected in the in-memory version of the model as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `user` has many `role`, you need a query to get all roles.
For example, if you attach new roles to a user, and that user has already another roles, then there will be a confusion.
You may try to set an attribute to your model after calling `attach` method, to do this please read the [last thing on the Laravel Eloquent doc](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent)

```
protected $appends = array('local_roles');
```

**Edit**

Even if you pass a model instead of id (with `save` method), it will not be added to the collection, and I find it more logical. Because as I already said, it may be a difference between the database and the model. Let me explain more clearly:

```
Role table   
-------------
| id| name  |
-------------
| 1 | admin |
-------------
| 2 | root  |
-------------

role_user table
-----------------
|role_id|user_id|
-----------------
| 1     |  1    |
-----------------
| 2     |  1    |
-----------------

user table
-----------
|id| name |
-----------
| 1| razor|
-----------
```

Now, **suppose** the `attach`(or `save`) method can add the model to the collection.If you do

```
$user = User::find(2); // without "with('roles')"
//Then you add a new role
$role = new Role;
$role->name = 'another_role';
$user->roles()->save($role);
```

Then, you will have in your model

```
"roles":[{"id":"3","name":"another_role","pivot":{"user_id":"1","role_id":"3"}}]
```

witch contradicts the results from the database. This problem does not appear in `belongs_to` and `has_one` relations, because there is only one model associated and even if you don't use `with` method, you get the same result. But in `many` relations(belongstomany,hasmany,hasmanythrough), the result will be depend on the use of the `with` method.

Comment: So are you saying that the new role I attach will not show up in the model until I reload it from the database?

Comment: yes but I'm not sure, maybe someone can give a better solution

Comment: Yes, that's right, attached model is not added to the collection. 
It can't be added to the collection by default since you can pass simple `id` instead of a model, so it would require to query the DB after all. 
I find it as a bug or at least big inconsistency of Eloquent, and probably the best would be to reload the relation after attach.